# LOCAL meaning in Macro

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm using local defined labels in Macros in order to make loops there and I want to understand the real its working principle. For example, Macro is just a pattern, inserted in my code, and I define a local label there with a same name every time and how compiler knows that i should jump to label inserted in same Macro, but not declared earlier. I'm using Intel 8086 architecture and I didn't find information.

Comment: The compiler will probably somehow mangle the label name by prefixing/suffixing some random string to it every time it is inserted into code (the random part designed in a way to never clash with legit user labels, often using character which is illegal for ordinary user labels to distinguish them, but legal for compiler).

Comment: If you use a macro more than once in the same program, and the assembler defines that data item or label for each occurrence, the duplicate names would cause the assembler to generate an error message. To ensure that each generated name is an unique code, the LOCAL directive is placed immediately after the MACRO statement, even before comments.